# Minimizing the amplitude of this sum.

Tags: matrix-equations

I am trying to solve this min-max problem.Please guide me how to approach this.

Please consider my Problem statement as:

```
Y=e * a ; where "e" & "a"=exponential phase factors & fixed complex numbers resp.
```

In Matlab;

```
M=4;N=256;
a = complex(randn(4,256),randn(4,256)); % coefficient matrix of "a"
```

[image] ... (1)

For a given θ the k-th row of (1) is:[image]

What choice or what range of [image] will minimize the peak of sum expression given in Eq. (2) ?

i.e.,[image]
      Subject to : [image]     and    m=1,2,…M.